# In Excel how to create 4 digit binary(0,1) with respect to successive order for N tiimes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, binary-files

**4 Digit Binary Algorithm decoding**

i have tried decoding the sequence but i couldn't, also tried in 16 ways to have four digit method.

for instance
0000
0001
1011
1000
0101
0101
1000
0100

Answer (score 0):

Use the `=DEC2BIN` function in combination with `BIN2DEC` function. For example if you want to list 0 to 15 and assuming the numbers will be in C column, in C1 enter the formula:

```
=DEC2BIN(0,4)
```

Then in C2:

```
=DEC2BIN(BIN2DEC($C1)+1,4)
```

Drag it down to fill the other cells.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: what if the case, if each digit is in separate column like c1,0 - c2,0 - c3,0- c4,0

Comment: @SasiTharan I don't understand your question. Separate columns, how? Show some examples.

Comment: in column C itself kept all the four digits(0000), my doubt is, if we kept the four digits in each columns like in C, D, E, F, will it works in same way!?

Comment: @SasiTharan Then the formula in D1 will be `=DEC2BIN(BIN2DEC(C$1)+1,4)`. The working of the formula remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title about creating a sequential set of four digit binary numbers:

Office365:

```
=DEC2BIN(SEQUENCE(16,,0),4)
```

And the results will spill down.

I'm not sure what you are asking in the body of your question about "*decoding the sequence*" or what you mean by the "*16 ways*".

If you are trying to convert this 16-bit binary number to it's decimal equivalent, one way is to multiply each `1` by 2^(location) where the rightmost location is `0`.

In Office 365, you could first remove the spaces (leaving the result as a text string), and then use:

```
=SUM(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)*2^SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,LEN(A1)-1,-1))
```

bearing in mind that Excel's decimal precision is approximately `15` digits; however, if your binary number is `16` digits, you won't have a problem as the maximum 16 digit binary number would be `65,535` or
(`(2^16)-1`)

See also [Bin2Dec for Numbers Longer than 10 Digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693029/bin2dec-for-numbers-longer-than-10-bits-in-excel)

If you mean something else, please clarify.